Visual Studio Code show different/random line numbers
Today I opened Visual Studio Code for my project. Everything was fine until I started editing my file and noticed that there is different or random numbers in "line numbers" column. Can someone explain this? Is this a bug or some Visual Studio Code's feature
Here is an example of what its looks like:
Visual Studio Code Line Numbers Column Image
I tried resetting Visual Studio Code, after resetting I came back to check, but it didn't help.

Welcome! Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled command in the command palette)? If not, then do an extension bisect to figure out what extension is causing it.
